# Publishing my WCF Service to my webhotel provider

Tags: wcf

I have made a small log service that i want to publish to a subdomain on my webhotel. I make the wcf service and test it locally - no problem. I then go to the [Build] menu and choose [Publish], type in my FTP location and publishes it to the location. No problems.

The problem arise when i need to use it, i try to navigate to the .svc file but gets this error:

This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem is that i cannot access the IIS configuration, since its on a hosted environment. The solution is described on my blog, since i had so much trouble getting this to work.
http://www.vikingworks.dk/post/WCF-Service-on-hosted-environment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your IIS configuration. This has already been discussed here: [WCF service startup error "This collection already contains an address with scheme http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561823/wcf-error-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-scheme-http)