# The authentication scheme ' NTLM' is not supported and other issues migrating from .asmx to wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I just switched my .asmx web service to WCF (both in .NET 3.5), and now I am getting

```
The authentication scheme ' NTLM' is not supported.
```

The only thing I've seen on google is where some w3svc/NTAuthenticationProviders setting had NTML instead of NTLM. I don't have that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - here is a summary of some annoying WCF issues that I encountered while migrating hopefully it helps someone.

Issue 1 - "This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection."

This is caused, I guess, by my web server having multiple web sites with multiple host headers. Solution found here: [WCF service startup error "This collection already contains an address with scheme http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561823/wcf-error-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-scheme-http).

I just added a baseAddressPrefixFilter:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://yoururl.blahblah.com/" />
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Issue 2: I got `The authentication scheme ' NTLM' is not supported.` error. I struggled with that for a while but eventually a reboot made that one go away (although I also did this (http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/705912-authentication-scheme-ntml-not-supported):

```
# change directory to c:\inetpub\admin scripts first
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/NTAuthenticationProviders "Negotiate,NTLM"
```

There was a space after the first comma in my config, no idea if that was causing an issue.

Issue 3: After a reboot, I got fun .404 errors.

My first guess at this was that wcf was not set up to be hosted on my server so I ran:
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx)

```
serviceModelReg.exe -i
```

But the real source of the 404 was caused by me trying to go to http://yoururl/somewhere.svc instead of http://yoururl.blahblah.com/somewhere.svc (i.e. my baseAddressPrefixFilter was causing my 404).

Hope this helps!