# sharepoint the server was unable to save the form at this time. please try again

Tags: sharepoint

I use a list in sharepoint. sometimes when i try to insert or edit a list item, sharepoint give this error in red color:

> sharepoint the server was unable to save the form at this time. please
>   try again

When i restart the iis, the error will gone but i can not restart iis repeatedly.
How can i resolve this error.

Comment: If occurs only on edit check if same item is altered from another part. When saving Sharepoint check if the item is changed from last time you read it from list.

Comment: This also should help [The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 5):

Please follow the below provided solutions one-by-one In order  and check to see the issue resolved.
Solution1.    Do IISRESET on SharePoint Servers
Solution2.    Restart all the SharePoint Servers
Solution3.    Enable anonymous authentication for the website in IIS.
Solution4.    Restart the SharePoint Search Host Controller in services.msc
Solution5.    Issue with the permission of user, could be The user doesn't have access to the site, but has access to the library.

If still the issue is not resolved by the above steps. Please do the below.

A.   Open IIS Manager on SharePoint server and do the following steps:

```
 a. Right Click on “Web Application” where you are getting error.
 b. Explore the Web Application.
 c. Open Web.config file.
 c. Search for serviceHostingEnvironment under system.serviceModel
 d. modify the entry as follows:
```

.

```
 e. Save the Web.config
 f. Reset IIS.
```

- See more at: http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.in/2014/07/the-server-was-unable-to-save-form-at.html#sthash.a7QLBqW7.dpuf

Comment: As per suggestion given on link page, I enabled Anonymous access for the site in IIS and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me in a fly (Y)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that this is because off low memory. pay attention that the minimum requirment for sharepoint is 16G and if sql server runs on the same server, you will need more than 16G ram. Add your memory and chack again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to save after restarting the timer job service and resetting IIS server:

- you have to restart the timer job service from `services.msc` on the SharePoint server.
- you can reset the IIS on server using command prompt: `IISRESET`

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**In case of you got “The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.” for all users.**

- SharePoint Search Host Controller service may need to restart to free up some memory space.
- Anonymous Authentication was disabled in IIS.
- “minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService” attribute is not set to serviceHostingEnvironment Tag in Web.Config.
- The farm wasn’t updated with at least March 2013 PU / Service Pack 1.

**In case of you got “The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.” for a specific user.**

- If your list has unique permissions and a user/group has permissions only on that list and has limited or no access at the site level, then you run into this error.

> For more details, please check **[The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again in SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the following line from the ServiceModel in web.config in order for this error to disappear:

multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"

Originally I applied this one to fix another error as suggested in this article: [WCF service startup error "This collection already contains an address with scheme http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561823/wcf-service-startup-error-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-sche)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur with low server memory. So just close the unwanted applications running to clear out the memory and try.

see the link for details: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013-error-the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again

Answer (score 0):

There was one script running on server,  which was consuming lots of memory. Killed it and nailed it!

Clearly RAM issue.