# This collection already contains an address with scheme Http

Tags: wcf

I want to have basic and Ws (over HTTP - Security is not a problem) and netTCP bindings at different urls.

```
<service name="WCFService.IHelloService" behaviorConfiguration="MyDefaultBehaviour">            
<endpoint address="basicHttpAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IIHelloService"/>
<endpoint address="netTCPAddress" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCFService.IIHelloService"/>            
<endpoint address="wsBindingAddress"
                      binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IIHelloService"
                      bindingConfiguration="wsBindingConfiguration"/>

<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

<host>
    <baseAddresses>                     
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8091/"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8095/"/>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8098/"/>                 
    </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Since I am having the multiple base address over the same protocol (http) I  have also enabled multipleSiteBindingsEnabled .

But still I am having the same problem.

How to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service startup error "This collection already contains an address with scheme http"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561823/wcf-service-startup-error-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-sche)

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, I have visited that link already. But it did not solve my problem. Thats why i have posted with my issue..

Comment: So you tried the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled and baseAddressPrefixFilters options?

Comment: Hi, please see the question. I have tried it. Since i am using FW 4.0 i have gone with the multisitebinding option.!